# Using sqlcipher with sqlite3 in Electron-Builder application

Tags: electron, sqlcipher, electron-builder, node-sqlite3

**Background**

I am trying to encrypt my sqlite database using sqlite3 and sqlcipher in an Electron application.

On the sqlite3 npm page [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3)

It says to install the build like this,

> yarn add sqlite3@4.0.8 --build-from-source --sqlite_libname=sqlcipher
>   --sqlite=`brew --prefix` --runtime=electron --target=4.0.0 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron

I have installed sqlcipher with home brew.

```
brew install sqlcipher
```

**Problem Example**

I am trying to create an encrypted database like this in my Electron application,

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./src/encryptedDB.sql');

db.serialize(function() {
      db.run("PRAGMA KEY = 'secret'");
      db.run("PRAGMA CIPHER = 'aes-256-cbc'");
      db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clients (info TEXT)');
      var stmt = db.prepare('INSERT INTO clients VALUES (?)');
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        stmt.run('wunO Background Client Number - ' + i);
      }
      stmt.finalize();
    });
```

This is not creating an encrypted database. I can open the file and see data inside of it.

**Question**

I am trying to figure out if this is a simple problem with my syntax or if maybe when the electron builder runs it's magic in the background, it is rebuilding sqlite and removing the `sqlcipher` build.

How do I create an encrypted sqlite build that will work on MacOS and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

> I can open the file and see data inside of it.

Since it's not asking for any type of passwords, then there must be problem with database creation. In the readme of Electron-builder it states that

> To ensure your native dependencies are always matched electron version, simply add script "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps" to your package.json.

Place the following line in your package.json and repeat the installation process again, this resolved the problem for me.

```
"postinstall": "install-app-deps",
```

Also, I have created a small Vue + Electron + Vuetify + SQLite (with Seqlize & Sqlcipher) starter kit that has all the things you need already setup. The source code to generate encrypted database can be found in `src/renderer/models.js` give it a look.

https://github.com/rizalishan/vue-electron-starter

Comment: @journeyapps/sqlcipher seems to not have been updated recently. Are you aware of this project is active? I notice that we can not use Electron 4 and it seems to be dependent on Electron 2. Do you know anything about that? We were really asking this question to understand how to get sqlcipher working with sqlite3 in our app so we can use the newest versions of the dependencies. I am afraid this package you are using may be outdated and does not look like it is being updated.